# Sealed classes generics

Tags: kotlin, generics, sealed-class

I have this scenario where I have a super abstract class that emits different types of events using Kotlin `sealed classes`.

These events are modeled as follows.

```kotlin
sealed class BaseEvent {
    object ConnectionStarted : BaseEvent()
    object ConnectionStopped : BaseEvent()
}

sealed class LegacyEvent : BaseEvent() {
    object TextChanged : LegacyEvent()
    object TextCleared : LegacyEvent()
}

sealed class AdvancedEvent : BaseEvent() {
    object ButtonClick : AdvancedEvent()
    object ButtonLongClick : AdvancedEvent()
}
```

And here are the classes that emit these events

```kotlin
abstract class BaseViewModel<E : BaseEvent> {

    private fun startConnection() {
        emit(BaseEvent.ConnectionStarted) // <-- Error
    }

    fun emit(event: E){
        //...
    }
}

class LegacyBaskan : BaseViewModel<LegacyEvent>() {
    fun textChanged() {
        emit(LegacyEvent.TextChanged) // <-- Works
    }
}

class AdvancedBaskan : BaseViewModel<AdvancedEvent>() {
    fun buttonClicked() {
        emit(AdvancedEvent.ButtonClick) // <-- Works
    }
}
```

Here, it only works for the subclass and I can emit any event in the `LegacyEvent` or `AdvancedEvent` in their associated classes. However, for the `BaseBaskan` class, I can't emit the events from the `BaseEvent` although I stated that the generic type `E` must extend the `BaseEvent`.

I need each subclass to have access to its own events as well as the superclass events, but not the other subclasses' events.

**How can I still emit events from `BaseEvent` in the base class, while giving each class the access to emit its own events only?**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're confused about why it's not letting you emit the item from the base class. Since E could be any subtype of BaseEvent, if your class could emit `ConnectionStarted`, then it would be violating its contract any time it is declared as a `BaseViewModel<AnythingBesidesConnectionStarted>`.

Only way I can think of to make this work is have both private and public versions of the `emit` function. You might have to change code elsewhere in your class that you haven't shown. If there's some function that returns `E`, you will have to change it so it returns `BaseEvent`.

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<E : BaseEvent> {

    private fun startConnection() {
        emitInternal(BaseEvent.ConnectionStarted)
    }

    private fun emitInternal(event: BaseEvent) {
      //...
    }

    fun emit(event: E){
        emitInternal(event)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't emit `BaseEvent.ConnectionStarted` in `BaseViewModel` (and other events as well) because `E` is not defined yet, so the type system can't be sure that you won't emit events of another subtype breaking generic type invariance.

Just add an overloaded private version, which accepts `BaseEvent` argument (you'll need some `@JvmName` annotation to make it compilable for JVM target):

```kotlin
abstract class BaseViewModel<E : BaseEvent> {
    private fun startConnection() {
        emit(BaseEvent.ConnectionStarted)
    }

    @JvmName("emitBaseEvent")
    private fun emit(event: BaseEvent) {
        //...
    }

    fun emit(event: E) {
        emit(event as BaseEvent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need contravariance, which can be achieved using `in`.  Assuming your base class only has methods such as `emit` that use type `E` as parameter type, not as return type, then:

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<in E : BaseEvent> {
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections.